# Preventing users from abusing an image deletion script

Tags: php

Basically the following for the core part:

```
$file = basename($_GET['f']);
$directory = "/var/www/site/";
$file = $directory . $file;
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$md5check = md5($file);
$md5check = substr($md5check, 0, 5);

if ($md5check == $hash) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
    else {
        die('error');
    }
}
else {
    header('Location: error');
    exit;
}
```

I realise using the users input is asking for trouble, but how can I get the server to 'locate' the file to delete? Am I somehow able to escape injections?
The user would be loading http://site.com/?f=test.jpg&h=hashc

Also is there any other hash systems besides MD5 which is separate for each location of a file? 
eg. 
 
file1.rar downloaded at 12:00am = differenthash 
    file1.rar downloaded at 11:00pm = randomhash
file1.rar is the same file in both scenarios.

versus md5:
file1.rar downloaded at 12:00am = randomhash 
    file1.rar downloaded at 11:00pm = randomhash
file1.rar is the same file in both scenarios.

Comment: Using only the first 5 characters of a md5-hash just isn't that safe. I would recommend using sha1 + a salt (at least). Also, to be sure, check whether the filename starts with ../ or /../ (since relative filenames are often enabled by PHP).

Comment: @Tim van Elsloo thanks for that. Will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using `basename` which should limit the attack vector greatly (as the user can't delete files from a different directory), however letting the user have access to delete files from /var/ is a **very** bad idea as the user would be able to pass any non-image file across too.

Can you not have some path relative to your web root rather than a very important system directory?

Extra security could include (note that this list is not at all exhaustive..):

1. User checking: Check that the web server user owns the file the user is requesting to delete.
2. Store uploaded files in the database and check that they exist and have been uploaded by our script before allowing deletion.
3. As above, move the files out of the system directory.
4. Use stronger hashing (ie. salts!).
5. Restrict this to a logged in user and log all actions, if somebody tries to delete a file it's logged and you know exactly who it was.

Comment: I should point out the actual script has `/var/www/site` (my site root).

Comment: In that case shouldn't the uploaded files be within `/var/www/site` rather than `/var`?

Comment: Correct, uploaded files are in `/var/www/site`

Comment: and as Tim mentioned in comment, DISSALLOW `..` and `/` just be brutal about it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just quickly how would I go about disallowing those two things?

Comment: Then you should be good to go, I wouldn't worry too much about the hashing, but more about ensuring the user has a valid login session before deleting a file. You could even tag files based on username so the user `jimbob` can only delete files starting with `jimbob_` (and they're automatically uploaded/named like that) or something. Trivial things such as this will go a long way!

Comment: I've implemented the SHA1 + Salt method suggested above. I'm going to try implement an API system to ensure some sort of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As @rudi_visser said, best way is white-listing, And store the uploaded files+data in the database.
And when the user tries to delete the file, make sure it's him, and make sure the file is uploaded (exists in the "uploaded" table not a part of your script/system).

Comment: I'd like to stick away from a DB, I understand it's the most secure though. And also the script is not for users to 'sign up', it classes everyone as the same. Thanks though :-)